# How to avoid repetitive code block of an if conditional?

Tags: python

I have some code in python, based on a specific argument I code it like below. I want to avoid repeating the same code blocks, I don't think it's intelligent or aesthetic.

```
If arg is x:
Do_1(x)
Do_2
Do_3
...
else:
Do_1(arg)
Do_2
Do_3
...
```

Alternatives?

Edit: sorry for ambiguous question, the actual code is:

for k in range(0,21):

```
iteration_directory = '%s/%s_round_%s' %(os.getcwd(), structure_name, k)

if not os.path.exists('%s/%s_round_%s' %(os.getcwd(), structure_name, k)):
    os.makedirs('%s/%s_round_%s' %(os.getcwd(), structure_name, k))

if start_model == 'null':

    if os.path.isfile( '%s/%s.1.silent' % (iteration_directory, structure_name))==False:
        Parallel(n_jobs=num_cores)(delayed(fragment_search_nomodel)(iteration_directory, rosetta_path, fasta, frag_file, structure_name, map_file, i) for i in residues)

    if os.path.isfile( '%s/scores1' % (iteration_directory))==False:
        fragment_score(rosetta_path, iteration_directory, structure_name)

    if os.path.isfile( '%s/assembled.1_0001.silent' % (iteration_directory))==False:
        Parallel(n_jobs=num_cores)(delayed(fragment_assembly)(rosetta_path, iteration_directory, structure_name, i) for i in residues)

    consensus_assignment(rosetta_path, iteration_directory, structure_name, k)

    start_model = '%s/%s_round_%s.pdb' % (os.getcwd(), structure_name, k) 


    print('Time for round #%s is: ' %k, datetime.now() - startTime)           

else:

    coverage = model_coverage(start_model,fasta)

    if coverage <= 70:

        if os.path.isfile( '%s/%s.1.silent' % (iteration_directory, structure_name))==False:
            Parallel(n_jobs=num_cores)(delayed(fragment_search)(iteration_directory, rosetta_path, fasta, frag_file, start_model, structure_name, map_file, i) for i in residues)

        if os.path.isfile( '%s/scores1' % (iteration_directory))==False:
            fragment_score(rosetta_path, iteration_directory, structure_name)

        if os.path.isfile( '%s/assembled.1_0001.silent' % (iteration_directory))==False:
            Parallel(n_jobs=num_cores)(delayed(fragment_assembly)(rosetta_path, iteration_directory, structure_name, i) for i in residues)

        consensus_assignment(rosetta_path, iteration_directory, structure_name, k)

        start_model = '%s/%s_round_%s.pdb' % (os.getcwd(), structure_name, k) 

        print('Time for round #%s is: ' %k, datetime.now() - startTime)
```

Comment: In Python indentation is a critical part of valid syntax. Please fix your indentation so your intent is clear.

Comment: Do_2 and Do_3 can just be done after the `if else` block and unintended, such that they are always executed.

Comment: You only pass `x` if it's the same as `arg`, so you don't need an `if`, just always pass `arg`.

Answer (score 2):

Seems

```
Do_1(arg)
Do_2()
Do_3()
```

will get executed regardless of your if clause, because regardless of arg value you're passing it to Do_1() method.

Comment: Please take a look at the actual code to know what I mean. I apologize for being vague with the question.

Answer (score 1):

Although the two if/else cases are equivalent, this seems to be what you are after:

```
if arg is x:
    Do_1(x)
else:
    Do_1(arg)
Do_2
Do_3
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could make the parameter value of Do_1 conditional:

```
Do_1(x if arg is x else arg)
Do_2()
Do_3()
```